# hover(). doesn't work on images inside button element in Firefox

Tags: jquery, hover, imagebutton

I have a script that changes images on hover.
It works on all images in Mozilla except when I have an image inside button element. It does work fine in IE though.

Here's the function:

```
$('.button').each(function(){
    var imgFile = $(this).attr('src') ;
    var preloadImage = new Image();
    var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
    preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt, '_over$1');
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', preloadImage.src);
    }, function(){
        $(this).attr('src', imgFile);
    });
});
```

Here's html:

```
<div class='preview_bottom'>

<div class='bold'>
If you are ready<br> to submit: <br>

<form action="index.php?p=submit" method="post">
<p>
<button type="submit" name="submit"><img src="images/submit.jpg" alt="" class="button"/>    </button>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted2" value="TRUE">
</p>
</form>
</div>

<div class='bold'>
If you need to make any changes before submitting: <br>

<form action="index.php?p=preview" method="post">
<p>
<button type="submit" name="changeorder" ><img src="images/change.jpg" alt="" class="button"/></button>
</p>
</form>
</div>

</div>
```

Can some one help me to make it work in FF? I've tried using first-child or find("img") for button element to select image inside but that doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('button').each(function(){
    var imgFile = $('.button',this).attr('src') ;
    var preloadImage = new Image();
    var imgExt = /(\.\w{3,4}$)/;
    preloadImage.src = imgFile.replace(imgExt, '_over$1');
    $(this).hover(function(){
        $('.button',this).attr('src', preloadImage.src);
    }, function(){
        $('.button',this).attr('src', imgFile);
    });
});
```